# subdomain causing lame server

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, dns-zone

i'm playing around with a DNS on localhost and i'm trying to add a subdomain but syslog reports it as a lame server.

i've defined my subdomain in my .db file while as follows

```
domain. IN SOA ns1.domain mail.domain (
      ....

 )

 IN NS ns1.domain
 ns1.domain. IN A 192.168.0.1

 subdomain IN NS ns1.subdomain.domain.
 ns1.subdomain.domain. IN A 192.168.0.1
```

doing dig @localhost ns1.subdomain.domain returns no answers and syslog shows it as a lame server.

or is this correct behaviour from a subdomain?

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

consist of the following lines

```
zone "domain"{
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/dnstest.db";
};
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `IN NS ns1.domain`
It should have a trailing `.`, e.g. `IN NS ns1.domain.`

Comment: and the same for SOA record.

Comment: Yeah... was just going to say... (will post as an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have both:

```
zone "domain"{
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/dnstest.db";
};
zone "subdomain.domain"{
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/subdomain.dnstest.db";
};
```

To be authoritative for the subdomain, you need a full set of SOA records, not just NS records in the parent zone.